# Best way to automate Azure / Exchange Online tasks

Tags: azure-devops, automation

In our company we automated certain things for our customers:

- Reporting, (counting Azure AD accounts, systems, mailboxes);
- Create user (setting all permissions);
- Create mailboxes;
- managing tickets in ITSM;
- Delete user .

We did use a lot of Powershell scripts and Azure Devops to automate these tasks. Now with the deprecation of basic authentication, we had to change our scripts and the way of authentication to all of our customers' Exchange Online. This made us think, is there a better way to set this up not to have these problems? We are already working with configfiles, modules, classes in our scripts.
What would be the best way to automate these tasks and not have the rework when Microsoft changes the authentication method?
Another question what would be a way to automate these tasks in low code?

The situation is that we make connection with the Azure Platform from our customers.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you already work with modules and classes you should probably write a single "authentication" module/class that is then used in all of the subsequent scripts. If and when MS change the authentication method again - one only needs to change this one class that is called by every other script.

In terms of "low code" - it depends on what these tasks are doing.. but, one is able to use the Power Platform Office365 Connector and from there it is possible to query AAD. There is also the GraphAPI.

It really depends on your use case but the following link may be of some assistance with the "low code" question:

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Query-Active-Directory/td-p/724376